# Perl problems printing output to a new file

Tags: perl

I want to remove all lines in a text file that start with HPL_  I have acheived this and can print to screen, but when I try to write to a file, I just get the last line of the amended text printed in the new file.  Any help please!

```
open(FILE,"<myfile.txt"); 
@LINES = <FILE>; 
close(FILE); 
open(FILE,">myfile.txt"); 
foreach $LINE (@LINES) { 
@array = split(/\:/,$LINE); 


my $file = "changed";

open OUTFILE, ">$file" or die "unable to open $file $!";

print OUTFILE $LINE unless ($array[0] eq "HPL_");

} 
close(FILE); 
close (OUTFILE);




exit;
```

Comment: Nobody wants to, nor should ever have to, debug Perl code that doesn't have `use strict; use warnings` at the top of it. It is pure madness to even try. And in a modern Perl programming environment, you want to also identify the version of Perl you're running with `use v5.12` or whatnot, and also have a `use autodie` if you are 5.10.1 or better. Otherwise it is just too hard.

Answer (score 8):

You just want to remove all lines that start with `HPL_`? That's easy!

```
perl -pi -e 's/^HPL_.*//s' myfile.txt
```

Yes, it really is just a one-liner. :-)

Comment: Good answer, and I upvoted, but I would also bet that this was just a part of the whole problem, and the actual issue is more complex. In other words, you may have answered the question, but not the real need. Not criticizing; just guessing.

Comment: Hmm, ok, well that was a lot easier than I thought it would be!  Thanks :-)

Comment: Won't that leave blank lines where `HPL_` used to be? When I try it, I have to explicitly add `\n` to remove the blank line.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use the one-liner, re-write the "write to file" portion as follows:

```
my $file = "changed";
open( my $outfh, '>', $file ) or die "Could not open file $file: $!\n";
foreach my $LINE (@LINES) { 
  my @array = split(/:/,$LINE);
  next if $array[0] eq 'HPL_';
  print $outfh $LINE;
}
close( $outfh );
```

Note how you are `open()`ing the file each time through the loop. This is causing the file to only contain the last line, as using `open()` with `>` means "overwrite what's in the file". That's the major problem with your code as it stands.

**Edit:** As an aside, you want to clean up your code. Use lexical filehandles as I've shown. Always add the three lines that tchrist posted at the top of every one of your Perl programs. Use the three-operator version of `open()`. Don't slurp the entire file into an array, as if you try to read a huge file it could cause your computer to run out of memory. Your program could be re-written as:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use autodie; 
use warnings FATAL => "all";

my $infile = "myfile.txt";
my $outfile = "changed.txt";

open( my $infh, '<', $infile );
open( my $outfh, '>', $outfile );
while( my $line = <$infh> ) {
    next if $line =~ /^HPL_/;
    print $outfh $line;
}
close( $outfh );
close( $infh );
```

Note how with `use autodie` you don't need to add `or die ...` to the `open()` function, as the `autodie` pragma handles that for you.

Comment: Pretty sure using lexical file handles in print require wrapping them in { and }.

Comment: @Rob: No they don't. Maybe in very ancient versions of Perl, but not since the 5.6 days at the very least. You only have to do that if you're doing things like storing filehandles in an array, in which case you have to do something like `print { $fhs[1] } $line`. See also [perldoc print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html).

Comment: @CanSpice Ahh. Well that shows how long I've been Perl-ing. :)

Comment: @Rob The dative slot must be either ⑴ a bareword like `STDOUT` or `IO::Handle`; ⑵ a scalar variable like `$fh` or `$His::fh`; ⑶ a brace-delimited block like `{ $Handles{$name} }`, `{ get_handle() }`, `{ $ok ? STDOUT : STDERR }`. This has zero to do with whether some variable holding an indirect handle should happen to be lexically scoped or not, nor whether it was autovivved.  It has always, always worked this way. You guys are forever mistakenly saying "lexical filehandles" when you do not mean that, and this leads to confusions. **Handle autovivification is orthogonal to lexical scoping!**

Comment: For example, these *are* lexical filehandles but not autovivved: `my $fh = local *FOO`, `my $fh = *STDOUT{IO}`,`my $fh = "main::STDOUT";`.  And this *is not* a lexical filehandle but is too autovivved: `open($His::fh=undef, "< /dev/null"); print $His::fh "stuff\n"`. And `$His::fh = new IO::Handle::` is neither lexical nor autovivved. You guys all keep saying lexical filehandle when you really mean autovivved handles, but these are completely disparate notions.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your code is that you open the file for output within your line-processing loop which, due to your use of the '>' form of open, opens the file each time for write, obliterating any previous content.

Move the invocation of open() to the top of your file, above the loop, and it should work.

Also, I'm not sure of your intent but at line 4 of your example, you reopen your input file for write (using '>'), which also clobbers anything it contains.

As a side note, you might try reading up on Perl's grep() command which is designed to do exactly what you need, as in:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, '<', 'myfile.txt') or die "failed to open input for read: $!";
my @lines = <$in> or die 'no lines to read from input';
close($in);

# collect all lines that do not begin with HPL_ into @result
my @result = grep ! /^HPL_/, @lines; 

open(my $out, '>', 'changed.txt') or die "failed to open output for write: $!";
print { $out } @result;
close($out);
```

Comment: That's correct, the file is overwritten by each open() in the loop. The first two opens are fine because the file is already loaded in the array before being closed and reopened. Note that to open a file in "append" mode and avoid overwriting its content is to open ">>$file". (not a good idea in this example)